# Concrete example of $K3$ surfaces with Picard number 18 and does not admit Shioda-Inose structure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, k3-surfaces

I am looking for some explicit examples of (elliptic) $K3$-families defined over a number field (better to be over $\mathbb{Q}$) with Picard number $18$ but does not admit Shioda-Inose structure, i.e. there is no primitive embedding from the transcendental lattice to $U^3$ ($U$ is the hyperbolic lattice). I am wondering is there good reference for that?

Comment: Title says Picard number 17; question text says 18.  Which do you want?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, sorry about that, I want the examples with Picard number 18.

Comment: OK, got it.  If you have a simple (i.e. low-discriminant) example of such a transcendental lattice $T$ then I can write down the surfaces.  (If you don't, I can hunt around for $T$ myself but it would take longer.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, thanks. I am sorry, I tried a little while but failed to find a such lattice which can't be primitively embedded into $U^{3}$ and is realizable.